# Why Biji comparing the Paula words with sun signs here?

Tags: meaning

In English Comedy-Drama movie [Bend It Like Beckham (2002)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bend_It_Like_Beckham), *Puala Paxton* insults Jess before her family with lesbian mark when she saw wearing her shoes which are provided by her own daughter *Juliette*. Actually *Biji* standing near them ask others by saying this lines.

> Puala Paxton: Get your lesbian feet out of my shoes!
>
> Biji: **Lesbian? Ηer birthday's in March. I thought she was a Pisces**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's meant to be a joke. Purposefully or not, Biji mistakes the word "lesbian" for an astrological sign. From Wikipedia,

> In [Western astrology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrological_sign), astrological signs are the twelve 30° sectors of the ecliptic, starting at the vernal equinox (one of the intersections of the ecliptic with the celestial equator), also known as the First Point of Aries. The order of the astrological signs is **Aries, Taurus, Gemini, Cancer, Leo, Virgo, Libra, Scorpio, Sagittarius, Capricorn, Aquarius and Pisces**.

The names of the signs are in bold. Roughly, people who are born between late February and mid-March are Pisces, and not some other sign called "Lesbian", which explains Biji's confusion.